# Can you help me with a web scraping problem, using BeautifulSoup class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below, I have written a Python code to scrape the image from a "LinkedIn post". First of all, I don't know how challenging it is to scrape from "LinkedIn", but the backend seems like it easily can be scraped. I would like to scrape the "src" of the image in the post.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/posts/aminayonis_stop-using-chatgpt-to-understand-academic-activity-7098649637711929344-cPm-?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop"

#make a request to the server using the requests module

page = requests.Session().get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

soup_find1 = soup.find("div", {"class": "ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper--use-img-tag display-flex"}).find("img")

print(soup_find1)
```

But, the output shows "None". I don't know where the mistake lies. If I provide soup.find_all("img"), it lists out all "img" tags, and I find it quite difficult to scrape the one I need. So, can any of you point out the error?

Comment: Dynamic pages modify their content from additional data downloaded after the page initially loads. This mean the content you want isn't originally in the page itself. Additionally, sites like linkedin, do not want you downloading their content like that and so take measures to prevent it.

Comment: use the selenium to crawl

Comment: @jiu_Zou, would it be possible for you to provide it as an answer? I would highly appreciate it.  The fact is I am learning scraping using BeautifulSoup class, and I have only rudimentary knowledge of using selenium.

Answer (score 1):

use selenium

[https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net](https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/114.0.1823.67/edgedriver_win64.zip)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver import EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/posts/aminayonis_stop-using-chatgpt-to-understand-academic-activity-7098649637711929344-cPm-?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop"
service=Service(executable_path = r'C:\Users\10696\Desktop\access\zhihu\msedgedriver\msedgedriver.exe')
edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
edge_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
edge_options.add_argument('lang=zh-CN,zh,zh-TW,en-US,en')
edge_options.add_argument("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")#

driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options, service = service)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper"))
pag = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper")
pag = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", pag)

table = soup(pag, "html.parser")
k = table.find_all("img")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. For me it raises error : raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: also, the class name I have noticed was " ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper--use-img-tag display-flex
        
        " in the actual post, whereas In your code, it is a trimmed version.

Comment: I can not get the website url because the country policy constraint.  I think you can deal the problem by youself.